# Cannot fully symbolicate iOS crash log

Tags: iphone, ios, xcode, symbolicatecrash, symbolicate

I've probably read upwards of 20 articles and forum posts on this subject and I still can't get it working.

My app seems to symbolicate just fine but I can't symbolicate system calls, which is where the majority of crash logs I receive seem to be crashing.

I have tried:

- Multiple versions of Xcode
- Using the patched symbolicatecrash script on GitHub
- Using mdimport to import both the app archive and the Xcode app
- Connecting my iPad running iOS 6 to Xcode so that it can scan it (a look inside the Xcode bundle reveals a folder called "6.0 (10A403)" inside the DeviceSupport directory, which is the final release of iOS 6)
- Importing the crash log into Xcode. It fails with no error. The only way to make it import is to copy and Incident Indentifier and CrashReporterKey fields from another log but it still fails to symbolicate system calls.

Why is this not working? How are others managing to get this to work? (Note: I have had this problem for a long time so it is nothing to do with the new release of iOS 6 and Xcode 4.5.)

The script output is filled with lots of lines like this:

```
Searching in Spotlight for dsym with UUID of f167dacec44b3a86a8eee73400ff7a83
Running mdfind "com_apple_xcode_dsym_uuids == F167DACE-C44B-3A86-A8EE-E73400FF7A83"
@dsym_paths = (  )
@exec_names = (  )
Did not find executable for dsym
## Warning: Can't find any unstripped binary that matches version of /usr/lib/system/libsystem_kernel.dylib
```

I am using the following Terminal command:

```
/Applications/Xcode/Xcode4.5.app/Contents/Developer/Platforms/iPhoneOS.platform/Developer/Library/PrivateFrameworks/DTDeviceKit.framework/Versions/A/Resources/symbolicatecrash -v ~/Desktop/My\ App.crash /Users/me/Library/Developer/Xcode/Archives/2012-07-23/My\ App\ 1.1.6\ 7-23-12\ 11.20\ AM.xcarchive/Products/Applications/My\ App.app
```

This produces the following output:

```
Incident Identifier: [TODO]
CrashReporter Key:   [TODO]
Hardware Model:      iPad2,1
Process:         My App [393]
Path:            /var/mobile/Applications/E2A55086-4318-4A18-803D-60C8F02A7524/My App.app/My App
Identifier:      com.company.MyApp
Version:         1160
Code Type:       ARM (Native)
Parent Process:  launchd [1]

Date/Time:       2012-09-28 17:42:33 +0000
OS Version:      iPhone OS 6.0
Report Version:  104

Exception Type:  SIGSEGV
Exception Codes: SEGV_ACCERR at 0x9
Crashed Thread:  0

Thread 0 Crashed:
0   libobjc.A.dylib                     0x399625b0 0x3995f000 + 13744
1   UIKit                               0x380cc781 0x37f98000 + 1263489
2   UIKit                               0x37fb2183 0x37f98000 + 106883
3   UIKit                               0x3806039f 0x37f98000 + 820127
4   UIKit                               0x37f9fc19 0x37f98000 + 31769
5   UIKit                               0x380b9be9 0x37f98000 + 1186793
6   UIKit                               0x380b950b 0x37f98000 + 1185035
7   UIKit                               0x380b8d31 0x37f98000 + 1183025
8   UIKit                               0x380803dd 0x37f98000 + 951261
9   UIKit                               0x3826d479 0x37f98000 + 2970745
10  UIKit                               0x37fa4837 0x37f98000 + 51255
11  UIKit                               0x37fa329b 0x37f98000 + 45723
12  UIKit                               0x37fae1ef 0x37f98000 + 90607
13  UIKit                               0x37faddbb 0x37f98000 + 89531
14  UIKit                               0x37f9b809 0x37f98000 + 14345
15  UIKit                               0x37f9b123 0x37f98000 + 12579
16  GraphicsServices                    0x39b245a3 0x39b1e000 + 26019
17  GraphicsServices                    0x39b241d3 0x39b1e000 + 25043
18  CoreFoundation                      0x37a05173 0x3796e000 + 618867
19  CoreFoundation                      0x37a05117 0x3796e000 + 618775
20  CoreFoundation                      0x37a03f99 0x3796e000 + 614297
21  CoreFoundation                      0x37976ebd 0x3796e000 + 36541
22  CoreFoundation                      0x37976d49 0x3796e000 + 36169
23  GraphicsServices                    0x39b232eb 0x39b1e000 + 21227
24  UIKit                               0x37fef301 0x37f98000 + 357121
25  My App                           0x00002ecf main (main.m:14)

(...removed for brevity...)

Thread 0 crashed with ARM (Native) Thread State:
    r0: 0x00309420     r1:      0x398cac29     r2:      0x38428185     r3:      0x3cab85fc
    r4: 0x00000001     r5:      0x38428185     r6:      0x0000007c     r7:      0x2fdfdc90
    r8: 0x00112f20     r9:      0x0e632b0a    r10:      0x398c9d92    r11:      0x3ccc4e8c
   r12: 0x3cc28d64     sp:      0x2fdfdc7c     lr:      0x380cc7cf     pc:      0x399625b0


Binary Images:
0x1000 - 0x2d000  My App armv7 <8c376a0dd06f391c8a2241924a496b72> /var/mobile/Applications/E2A55086-4318-4A18-803D-60C8F02A7524/My App.app/My App
0x3578a000 - 0x3594e000  Foundation armv7 <2e1ac190c4f837e2a1059043dd7b1c63> /System/Library/Frameworks/Foundation.framework/Foundation
0x37f98000 - 0x384ec000  UIKit armv7 <98789fe7c21b3fe0bf5c0bb36648147f> /System/Library/Frameworks/UIKit.framework/UIKit
0x34166000 - 0x3429f000  CoreGraphics armv7 <903960bfcfe93adb943752851f88491e> /System/Library/Frameworks/CoreGraphics.framework/CoreGraphics
0x389e6000 - 0x38a6c000  MessageUI armv7 <acd711b4e9cb3bdba768a884c4d6976a> /System/Library/Frameworks/MessageUI.framework/MessageUI
0x39182000 - 0x391b6000  CoreMIDI armv7 <9c1e141eaab43c44bef50146804890f2> /System/Library/Frameworks/CoreMIDI.framework/CoreMIDI
0x39b2a000 - 0x39b6a000  SystemConfiguration armv7 <44d84d23d10f344c90b4d9e9611ec976> /System/Library/Frameworks/SystemConfiguration.framework/SystemConfiguration
0x327bb000 - 0x32807000  libstdc++.6.dylib armv7 <55a7612b28c43cfcad7089b688591b80> /usr/lib/libstdc++.6.dylib
0x334df000 - 0x334e0000  libSystem.B.dylib armv7 <f2cad3bd15f63f448a9c5be732c65819> /usr/lib/libSystem.B.dylib
0x384fa000 - 0x384fb000  libgcc_s.1.dylib armv7 <b25697291f6237feb3458df23485a759> /usr/lib/libgcc_s.1.dylib
0x3796e000 - 0x37aa1000  CoreFoundation armv7 <e30fc309df7b3c9f8ac57f0f6047d65f> /System/Library/Frameworks/CoreFoundation.framework/CoreFoundation
0x3995f000 - 0x39a5e000  libobjc.A.dylib armv7 <5224e803eca737a4b2c6451d136b3d28> /usr/lib/libobjc.A.dylib
0x34b24000 - 0x34c6e000  libicucore.A.dylib armv7 <0253932c1b9038a0849ef73c38e076ca> /usr/lib/libicucore.A.dylib
0x37c1d000 - 0x37ccb000  libxml2.2.dylib armv7 <ef245c0afc113f54b6f30921671edab2> /usr/lib/libxml2.2.dylib
0x391bb000 - 0x391c8000  libz.1.dylib armv7 <a3bba3842596315a81aa171a8bbda7b5> /usr/lib/libz.1.dylib
0x37678000 - 0x3773e000  CFNetwork armv7 <3e973794a4d13428bb974edcb2027139> /System/Library/Frameworks/CFNetwork.framework/CFNetwork
0x3871b000 - 0x3874a000  Security armv7 <be87724ccad837479efd45ca9f2c6b2c> /System/Library/Frameworks/Security.framework/Security
0x32835000 - 0x3287f000  IOKit armv7 <c4786e65ac913839b1bb3b85a9c951fa> /System/Library/Frameworks/IOKit.framework/Versions/A/IOKit
0x335c4000 - 0x335db000  libCRFSuite.dylib armv7 <9b3fd56781103f209be2c43e48c1efc9> /usr/lib/libCRFSuite.dylib
0x32899000 - 0x3289a000  liblangid.dylib armv7 <a04b639c18593885bd81bfa623a6f07c> /usr/lib/liblangid.dylib
0x39937000 - 0x39944000  GenerationalStorage armv7 <74d50f4c8d243a35ad3ae89d85f2793a> /System/Library/PrivateFrameworks/GenerationalStorage.framework/GenerationalStorage
0x360cf000 - 0x360e3000  libc++abi.dylib armv7 <c5a5f03138353747b539e620ef2bb5c0> /usr/lib/libc++abi.dylib
0x33e05000 - 0x33e09000  libcache.dylib armv7 <e08b913e17753180b91728a8bd5dda7b> /usr/lib/system/libcache.dylib
0x3b84e000 - 0x3b855000  libcommonCrypto.dylib armv7 <690aaa493b5c3f9582499f174adf4964> /usr/lib/system/libcommonCrypto.dylib
0x3641d000 - 0x36420000  libcompiler_rt.dylib armv7 <7add7c91a2673641b0c5f0433a203da6> /usr/lib/system/libcompiler_rt.dylib
0x35e86000 - 0x35e8c000  libcopyfile.dylib armv7 <15aa2c3c8d523273913d4fc6717d3b7c> /usr/lib/system/libcopyfile.dylib
0x3524d000 - 0x3526b000  libdispatch.dylib armv7 <4abccf75caf33fa5a0c6037b2e1c5f41> /usr/lib/system/libdispatch.dylib
0x3928a000 - 0x3928c000  libdnsinfo.dylib armv7 <6c912cedc1e938ad914dfce91a529b68> /usr/lib/system/libdnsinfo.dylib
0x389e4000 - 0x389e6000  libdyld.dylib armv7 <3a149b4730663b1ea84e4a0a68ccc689> /usr/lib/system/libdyld.dylib
0x36b70000 - 0x36b71000  libkeymgr.dylib armv7 <8a2e3a8fdf9335e2867a33e2d1a9baf8> /usr/lib/system/libkeymgr.dylib
0x37b3b000 - 0x37b41000  liblaunch.dylib armv7 <021ff140d6003f3281dfa29b79fa9e6e> /usr/lib/system/liblaunch.dylib
0x33557000 - 0x3355b000  libmacho.dylib armv7 <2a9fe0b48f473d0f8fe2bf076cd12753> /usr/lib/system/libmacho.dylib
0x3630f000 - 0x36311000  libremovefile.dylib armv7 <6a0dd04f0710329b9c1722db2235f5c3> /usr/lib/system/libremovefile.dylib
0x32791000 - 0x32792000  libsystem_blocks.dylib armv7 <993c9bfe8bf031548b9ddba63cc17015> /usr/lib/system/libsystem_blocks.dylib
0x34fae000 - 0x35035000  libsystem_c.dylib armv7 <d45dc8901531343caf9b7e703d3eba50> /usr/lib/system/libsystem_c.dylib
0x37acb000 - 0x37ad2000  libsystem_dnssd.dylib armv7 <6c1c1aaf9a3537d7ada4b519d14da7ab> /usr/lib/system/libsystem_dnssd.dylib
0x34627000 - 0x34640000  libsystem_info.dylib armv7 <be3d5625aed733ffb2d53400655fe110> /usr/lib/system/libsystem_info.dylib
0x39a7f000 - 0x39a96000  libsystem_kernel.dylib armv7 <f167dacec44b3a86a8eee73400ff7a83> /usr/lib/system/libsystem_kernel.dylib
0x36218000 - 0x36235000  libsystem_m.dylib armv7 <7b2a25c750063de480f6a691f716b9d7> /usr/lib/system/libsystem_m.dylib
0x338b3000 - 0x338c2000  libsystem_network.dylib armv7 <d0fb0eda6cb53a4da859d598c59e7522> /usr/lib/system/libsystem_network.dylib
0x3aab0000 - 0x3aab8000  libsystem_notify.dylib armv7 <6e39f8511ecc3c3489829714eb6fde12> /usr/lib/system/libsystem_notify.dylib
0x34659000 - 0x3465b000  libsystem_sandbox.dylib armv7 <46cd200d99323aebbf6d81e5fb16424f> /usr/lib/system/libsystem_sandbox.dylib
0x37bd3000 - 0x37bd4000  libunwind.dylib armv7 <85e7546accc23ae1a973da4758512b7f> /usr/lib/system/libunwind.dylib
0x372d8000 - 0x372ee000  libxpc.dylib armv7 <9fbb123276823c2383fc34b7a55404d7> /usr/lib/system/libxpc.dylib
0x3358e000 - 0x335c4000  libcorecrypto.dylib armv7 <ebd023957d853fa8bd35309592e92dac> /usr/lib/system/libcorecrypto.dylib
0x3937c000 - 0x39402000  libsqlite3.dylib armv7 <759ca29f533a33e88a81fddc3364bf19> /usr/lib/libsqlite3.dylib
0x34b17000 - 0x34b24000  libbsm.0.dylib armv7 <e98708fbfa683df2a91d45dc765071a7> /usr/lib/libbsm.0.dylib
0x37ecb000 - 0x37f6c000  UIFoundation armv7 <795a2f216cc3379c95eb645c633cc527> /System/Library/PrivateFrameworks/UIFoundation.framework/UIFoundation
0x3b7d0000 - 0x3b7d5000  IOSurface armv7 <1f598a3806073bdaa906c51dccc9429e> /System/Library/PrivateFrameworks/IOSurface.framework/IOSurface
0x3355b000 - 0x33563000  liblockdown.dylib armv7 <257ecb171a363e4298a63f72d7fffea2> /usr/lib/liblockdown.dylib
0x34d56000 - 0x34d5d000  MobileKeyBag armv7 <a81d768a49cf37a1a111594d39cea3fe> /System/Library/PrivateFrameworks/MobileKeyBag.framework/MobileKeyBag
0x3a9b5000 - 0x3a9c5000  CoreVideo armv7 <092f3aa965803a1aaea69af2ac5143f5> /System/Library/Frameworks/CoreVideo.framework/CoreVideo
0x36420000 - 0x3645f000  VideoToolbox armv7 <bfc75ceef01e366e8335949abf037d4b> /System/Library/Frameworks/VideoToolbox.framework/VideoToolbox
0x3ab6e000 - 0x3ab9c000  MobileAsset armv7 <23e6b8ea85dd3dea84d8c295b4777753> /System/Library/PrivateFrameworks/MobileAsset.framework/MobileAsset
0x39ae7000 - 0x39af5000  TelephonyUtilities armv7 <0e07c7484ca63c189fd19790eb48bb28> /System/Library/PrivateFrameworks/TelephonyUtilities.framework/TelephonyUtilities
0x35d6f000 - 0x35d8e000  WebBookmarks armv7 <012ed1a1f54a3d6d836e2836781d4f73> /System/Library/PrivateFrameworks/WebBookmarks.framework/WebBookmarks
0x34583000 - 0x3459b000  BackBoardServices armv7 <e3eb5191f83339a1abad4c332c1b9d83> /System/Library/PrivateFrameworks/BackBoardServices.framework/BackBoardServices
0x33f13000 - 0x33f1b000  XPCObjects armv7 <5bc4f7282e9d3945a6c1885217670667> /System/Library/PrivateFrameworks/XPCObjects.framework/XPCObjects
0x369a5000 - 0x36a5b000  CoreImage armv7 <ba744c4f6a1c3c0598de9d429022093a> /System/Library/Frameworks/CoreImage.framework/CoreImage
0x39a96000 - 0x39ab0000  DictionaryServices armv7 <e1f8d258d02c344cb0d17cec31818d3f> /System/Library/PrivateFrameworks/DictionaryServices.framework/DictionaryServices
0x39b1e000 - 0x39b2a000  GraphicsServices armv7 <c5879083e8693aba827c78a32abe2391> /System/Library/PrivateFrameworks/GraphicsServices.framework/GraphicsServices
0x3504c000 - 0x35225000  ImageIO armv7 <fdfa8aa6307235b29435e5c8f6bc9819> /System/Library/Frameworks/ImageIO.framework/ImageIO
0x371c2000 - 0x372d8000  QuartzCore armv7 <d96571a6986c3012b315cb860f4d65ca> /System/Library/Frameworks/QuartzCore.framework/QuartzCore
0x37d5c000 - 0x37d6e000  SpringBoardServices armv7 <22255260ec6436d19176696422441c40> /System/Library/PrivateFrameworks/SpringBoardServices.framework/SpringBoardServices
0x38833000 - 0x3886f000  AppSupport armv7 <74ed50d2f7d23ce696b029dd817749c0> /System/Library/PrivateFrameworks/AppSupport.framework/AppSupport
0x34520000 - 0x34583000  CoreText armv7 <4a0bece315e9316fa1aa1b5923740f55> /System/Library/Frameworks/CoreText.framework/CoreText
0x35558000 - 0x355b2000  MobileCoreServices armv7 <d831f1f9285535acac5035a29d84aaaf> /System/Library/Frameworks/MobileCoreServices.framework/MobileCoreServices
0x3abae000 - 0x3ac8b000  WebKit armv7 <73fa195f63bc32c29060ac0fecabdca6> /System/Library/PrivateFrameworks/WebKit.framework/WebKit
0x39b7c000 - 0x3a4ac000  WebCore armv7 <cd34aedf72653d1dbef6b14fdfd0c053> /System/Library/PrivateFrameworks/WebCore.framework/WebCore
0x34dae000 - 0x34e23000  ProofReader armv7 <cc89a352199a393ba0e46af69e670ef9> /System/Library/PrivateFrameworks/ProofReader.framework/ProofReader
0x32892000 - 0x32899000  libAccessibility.dylib armv7 <9e8bfe02e370375ea8439ab895528982> /usr/lib/libAccessibility.dylib
0x35d65000 - 0x35d66000  Accelerate armv7 <22bee3e96cbc3538bfc50ca5be618cc0> /System/Library/Frameworks/Accelerate.framework/Accelerate
0x346bc000 - 0x346e5000  PrintKit armv7 <a8ef6136b9773d42ac20f7eb54279039> /System/Library/PrivateFrameworks/PrintKit.framework/PrintKit
0x360fb000 - 0x36108000  libMobileGestalt.dylib armv7 <0338ce49444332ec88cfc45c624bb39b> /usr/lib/libMobileGestalt.dylib
0x3282f000 - 0x32835000  IOMobileFramebuffer armv7 <3a351ca1d4ae3146a787f3e13564294b> /System/Library/PrivateFrameworks/IOMobileFramebuffer.framework/IOMobileFramebuffer
0x3602d000 - 0x3602f000  CoreSurface armv7 <b3f9d4e8dd803a48b88c58a0663d92a3> /System/Library/PrivateFrameworks/CoreSurface.framework/CoreSurface
0x386cc000 - 0x38717000  libc++.1.dylib armv7 <a361a382693032b9bdfb2860033b3024> /usr/lib/libc++.1.dylib
0x334ca000 - 0x334d2000  OpenGLES armv7 <e035b741746c316dba8f1e59a568bf17> /System/Library/Frameworks/OpenGLES.framework/OpenGLES
0x3b6c9000 - 0x3b6ce000  libGFXShared.dylib armv7 <6a8f59f89218372d9f24c4193a179008> /System/Library/Frameworks/OpenGLES.framework/libGFXShared.dylib
0x35d1c000 - 0x35d20000  AggregateDictionary armv7 <20bde7d58a573f2fbd5d6458d4e50ef8> /System/Library/PrivateFrameworks/AggregateDictionary.framework/AggregateDictionary
0x3796c000 - 0x3796e000  IOAccelerator armv7 <de8af6be681832008d180d7424d55f0d> /System/Library/PrivateFrameworks/IOAccelerator.framework/IOAccelerator
0x33519000 - 0x33557000  libGLImage.dylib armv7 <7db25f3d55b93f31868e37326fba1e57> /System/Library/Frameworks/OpenGLES.framework/libGLImage.dylib
0x37b45000 - 0x37b46000  libCVMSPluginSupport.dylib armv7 <1fd63e8305ab3ca190b1ef6ab2555f9d> /System/Library/Frameworks/OpenGLES.framework/libCVMSPluginSupport.dylib
0x3aab8000 - 0x3ab1e000  CoreMedia armv7 <d227864b757e3a7ea5d7d96dcbb948fe> /System/Library/Frameworks/CoreMedia.framework/CoreMedia
0x33eee000 - 0x33ef4000  CrashReporterSupport armv7 <7bde3532f2953f3894eb725379575926> /System/Library/PrivateFrameworks/CrashReporterSupport.framework/CrashReporterSupport
0x35392000 - 0x353e9000  CoreAudio armv7 <a3a2eb3a29443b42a23aa8ecb1232846> /System/Library/Frameworks/CoreAudio.framework/CoreAudio
0x34733000 - 0x34789000  CoreTelephony armv7 <54708e241c5c3e2297c2fca0d685497d> /System/Library/Frameworks/CoreTelephony.framework/CoreTelephony
0x36023000 - 0x3602d000  AssetsLibraryServices armv7 <e51cbfefefbc30b6b47d99739123033e> /System/Library/PrivateFrameworks/AssetsLibraryServices.framework/AssetsLibraryServices
0x39a77000 - 0x39a7b000  MobileInstallation armv7 <e6b6ae9d4f5f3831a40fcc370afc1429> /System/Library/PrivateFrameworks/MobileInstallation.framework/MobileInstallation
0x3b75b000 - 0x3b780000  Bom armv7 <c76b4156e0463ecb922608d44c126d86> /System/Library/PrivateFrameworks/Bom.framework/Bom
0x39a7b000 - 0x39a7f000  MobileSystemServices armv7 <6edd9c74c5a73c33809152446abe1538> /System/Library/PrivateFrameworks/MobileSystemServices.framework/MobileSystemServices
0x3ab9c000 - 0x3aba6000  libbz2.1.0.dylib armv7 <5258dce78afc3fd7934a5674b92ad785> /usr/lib/libbz2.1.0.dylib
0x39431000 - 0x39434000  TCC armv7 <f641dd0500fa3f0087d93da665ea84b8> /System/Library/PrivateFrameworks/TCC.framework/TCC
0x3685f000 - 0x368ac000  IMFoundation armv7 <b1a5542b977e3ae683f40ee5755d5b32> /System/Library/PrivateFrameworks/IMFoundation.framework/IMFoundation
0x34d4e000 - 0x34d54000  CommonUtilities armv7 <cb484bdaf5003e4baa13f83bafff62a9> /System/Library/PrivateFrameworks/CommonUtilities.framework/CommonUtilities
0x35d20000 - 0x35d47000  libtidy.A.dylib armv7 <134c41c587fb33dca014bd525f68a0c7> /usr/lib/libtidy.A.dylib
0x336ad000 - 0x33854000  JavaScriptCore armv7 <6b14c224c0e0306aa9084679ec6a99d2> /System/Library/PrivateFrameworks/JavaScriptCore.framework/JavaScriptCore
0x35a14000 - 0x35b53000  vImage armv7 <a7fd7fcd7041356db2ca297402ab6e8c> /System/Library/Frameworks/Accelerate.framework/Frameworks/vImage.framework/vImage
0x3367d000 - 0x3367e000  vecLib armv7 <66204595f7653ef29e5e26cb8629177a> /System/Library/Frameworks/Accelerate.framework/Frameworks/vecLib.framework/vecLib
0x34cf4000 - 0x34d4e000  libvDSP.dylib armv7 <ad4c53081a263f0d96f63b9a80f2ae91> /System/Library/Frameworks/Accelerate.framework/Frameworks/vecLib.framework/libvDSP.dylib
0x32b2d000 - 0x32de3000  libLAPACK.dylib armv7 <dd6f3958c3d536d6be90836682d2ffee> /System/Library/Frameworks/Accelerate.framework/Frameworks/vecLib.framework/libLAPACK.dylib
0x32a49000 - 0x32b2d000  libBLAS.dylib armv7 <56d8e00447133cd89457deec007327cb> /System/Library/Frameworks/Accelerate.framework/Frameworks/vecLib.framework/libBLAS.dylib
0x3605c000 - 0x3606e000  libvMisc.dylib armv7 <a3d025234d1a3880a0e5f87879633ee0> /System/Library/Frameworks/Accelerate.framework/Frameworks/vecLib.framework/libvMisc.dylib
0x35227000 - 0x3524d000  OpenCL armv7 <f7706501012430fc94ed99006419fba9> /System/Library/PrivateFrameworks/OpenCL.framework/OpenCL
0x3a52b000 - 0x3a93f000  FaceCoreLight armv7 <0cb7a12beb3d32c1abd1834be8328b7c> /System/Library/PrivateFrameworks/FaceCoreLight.framework/FaceCoreLight
0x3a98f000 - 0x3a992000  libCoreVMClient.dylib armv7 <e57152bacb36350e8a023e0c1b540a0c> /System/Library/Frameworks/OpenGLES.framework/libCoreVMClient.dylib
0x38812000 - 0x38833000  libxslt.1.dylib armv7 <7f6f63b31f333c41952f685fdd54a6cb> /usr/lib/libxslt.1.dylib
0x36a82000 - 0x36b70000  libiconv.2.dylib armv7 <faa5abb937e3306ab87c7f7c38315839> /usr/lib/libiconv.2.dylib
0x36da1000 - 0x36db7000  libresolv.9.dylib armv7 <e79b59a3406f34d9b37f8085955115ce> /usr/lib/libresolv.9.dylib
0x3ac8b000 - 0x3af12000  AudioToolbox armv7 <6a4804d0e35e362dbad6f047c25227ca> /System/Library/Frameworks/AudioToolbox.framework/AudioToolbox
0x39357000 - 0x3935c000  FTClientServices armv7 <13aa63aa5e2e348ea289e0fd16585890> /System/Library/PrivateFrameworks/FTClientServices.framework/FTClientServices
0x36238000 - 0x362f3000  AddressBookUI armv7 <5c030d99a0113ceda2ae375d348e4cdb> /System/Library/Frameworks/AddressBookUI.framework/AddressBookUI
0x333f9000 - 0x334b3000  Message armv7 <c854843dec583b33a72a9fe047d20f0c> /System/Library/PrivateFrameworks/Message.framework/Message
0x37e66000 - 0x37ecb000  AddressBook armv7 <3c0d5a3207cf3771b0beb0cd8e8a6e12> /System/Library/Frameworks/AddressBook.framework/AddressBook
0x37b96000 - 0x37bd3000  DataAccess armv7 <bd40f7ec5a9c3df7b4a575fffc25c14f> /System/Library/PrivateFrameworks/DataAccess.framework/DataAccess
0x370e0000 - 0x37194000  EventKit armv7 <8dbff0bfcf833661827a76b9adb64d70> /System/Library/Frameworks/EventKit.framework/EventKit
0x38571000 - 0x3857c000  MailServices armv7 <f31a7844317a3f2484cffe092e9fd7c2> /System/Library/PrivateFrameworks/MailServices.framework/MailServices
0x345f0000 - 0x34627000  MIME armv7 <32427c81a9933c4796d1a37a88a3ac44> /System/Library/PrivateFrameworks/MIME.framework/MIME
0x3289a000 - 0x32965000  Celestial armv7 <1a048f93218d3551984b2d07e884694c> /System/Library/PrivateFrameworks/Celestial.framework/Celestial
0x39473000 - 0x39486000  DataAccessExpress armv7 <131d8cf4df333df3b8487ef93438e27c> /System/Library/PrivateFrameworks/DataAccessExpress.framework/DataAccessExpress
0x35997000 - 0x359e4000  QuickLook armv7 <ac70bd1a745e3402b9bcd484f34c4203> /System/Library/Frameworks/QuickLook.framework/QuickLook
0x34aa8000 - 0x34aab000  MessageSupport armv7 <44d449b4959a33b99d4ab4a9cd161ee6> /System/Library/PrivateFrameworks/MessageSupport.framework/MessageSupport
0x37d6e000 - 0x37e55000  AVFoundation armv7 <23a8a62a06b03cbcbe7659918951c9f3> /System/Library/Frameworks/AVFoundation.framework/AVFoundation
0x3aa1d000 - 0x3aa96000  IMCore armv7 <552805a4634630bbaad2bc9d862d7196> /System/Library/PrivateFrameworks/IMCore.framework/IMCore
0x3277b000 - 0x32781000  Marco armv7 <755b00548c863f939bf1409f03f2b3ad> /System/Library/PrivateFrameworks/Marco.framework/Marco
0x3385b000 - 0x33899000  FTServices armv7 <aa7fe75a69d538b2a80efa63e3484b2a> /System/Library/PrivateFrameworks/FTServices.framework/FTServices
0x3a4d2000 - 0x3a52b000  ManagedConfiguration armv7 <9d006173bfcc3001b45c44b8e78833ed> /System/Library/PrivateFrameworks/ManagedConfiguration.framework/ManagedConfiguration
0x36460000 - 0x36472000  Accounts armv7 <07b95faa96e73ffeb52694cbad7f3528> /System/Library/Frameworks/Accounts.framework/Accounts
0x360f6000 - 0x360f9000  OAuth armv7 <d3e2bc9ae64b31f0a89c52dc1c2797fc> /System/Library/PrivateFrameworks/OAuth.framework/OAuth
0x362f3000 - 0x36300000  AccountSettings armv7 <0b7524e9a8ef36bf9e9f6a5c445478af> /System/Library/PrivateFrameworks/AccountSettings.framework/AccountSettings
0x35f00000 - 0x35f16000  libmis.dylib armv7 <3afeeea531013420af75315d8d6dd332> /usr/lib/libmis.dylib
0x35d47000 - 0x35d65000  PersistentConnection armv7 <8e4d21f987d4334e927222c28ff1130b> /System/Library/PrivateFrameworks/PersistentConnection.framework/PersistentConnection
0x3a9fc000 - 0x3a9fe000  DataMigration armv7 <25f8874067393208acc083124bc3eb86> /System/Library/PrivateFrameworks/DataMigration.framework/DataMigration
0x36a62000 - 0x36a67000  CertUI armv7 <7e4aee03dc3735559f1270e504d94f02> /System/Library/PrivateFrameworks/CertUI.framework/CertUI
0x33619000 - 0x3361d000  ActorKit armv7 <64235ea1a8b73d23a4a9836410424b6b> /System/Library/PrivateFrameworks/ActorKit.framework/ActorKit
0x36d58000 - 0x36d7c000  MobileSync armv7 <986186369add34f1be231f5a47d2fd2c> /System/Library/PrivateFrameworks/MobileSync.framework/MobileSync
0x392d9000 - 0x392f3000  Notes armv7 <b8fb864f5973319083f926d9a570734e> /System/Library/PrivateFrameworks/Notes.framework/Notes
0x37ada000 - 0x37b33000  CoreLocation armv7 <3235bde1608331bebc291891405896c6> /System/Library/Frameworks/CoreLocation.framework/CoreLocation
0x36661000 - 0x3669d000  iCalendar armv7 <d5f593ead35b38a98d6cfd4a243e0172> /System/Library/PrivateFrameworks/iCalendar.framework/iCalendar
0x355b2000 - 0x35768000  CoreData armv7 <a42aa4f0f01833c390bc8c6c394dda1c> /System/Library/Frameworks/CoreData.framework/CoreData
0x37757000 - 0x37846000  GeoServices armv7 <6af26ce81030330b97122ba8c1deaaa2> /System/Library/PrivateFrameworks/GeoServices.framework/GeoServices
0x37aa1000 - 0x37aaa000  ProtocolBuffer armv7 <359ccc7700c93d58adbbd74ecfda80d9> /System/Library/PrivateFrameworks/ProtocolBuffer.framework/ProtocolBuffer
0x37889000 - 0x37899000  MobileDeviceLink armv7 <5c91ef875c5931a1a26e227ddfd7262d> /System/Library/PrivateFrameworks/MobileDeviceLink.framework/MobileDeviceLink
0x3b71f000 - 0x3b753000  AppleAccount armv7 <2af09d814a5a382192613b68b9327d49> /System/Library/PrivateFrameworks/AppleAccount.framework/AppleAccount
0x3853a000 - 0x3856b000  ContentIndex armv7 <25cc27c7fdac34e6ae5e057c048a3e21> /System/Library/PrivateFrameworks/ContentIndex.framework/ContentIndex
0x34ce1000 - 0x34cef000  ApplePushService armv7 <60dbc7ab243435e099e19bdd3fa83dbb> /System/Library/PrivateFrameworks/ApplePushService.framework/ApplePushService
0x3b8b7000 - 0x3bb3d000  MediaToolbox armv7 <a1df6dd0733233d3b1cba9cddf3991f6> /System/Library/Frameworks/MediaToolbox.framework/MediaToolbox
0x3691d000 - 0x369a5000  CoreMotion armv7 <537e5776244f3ef5a355f8fd14a72a22> /System/Library/Frameworks/CoreMotion.framework/CoreMotion
0x3afa3000 - 0x3b04f000  MediaControlSender armv7 <fba51e235adc368b8132db578723a8fa> /System/Library/PrivateFrameworks/MediaControlSender.framework/MediaControlSender
0x36bc5000 - 0x36c9e000  StoreServices armv7 <9da3466c9cf13402a9f0412065f0ada7> /System/Library/PrivateFrameworks/StoreServices.framework/StoreServices
0x32965000 - 0x3296f000  MobileWiFi armv7 <43de6d03af0838f2a1eeec10d4149e9d> /System/Library/PrivateFrameworks/MobileWiFi.framework/MobileWiFi
0x34da4000 - 0x34dac000  CaptiveNetwork armv7 <c1a469c6ca4a3718bef325ec0f4e1885> /System/Library/PrivateFrameworks/CaptiveNetwork.framework/CaptiveNetwork
0x38acf000 - 0x38ae8000  EAP8021X armv7 <034c653573c233f08edf67e516d66097> /System/Library/PrivateFrameworks/EAP8021X.framework/EAP8021X
0x33027000 - 0x331c0000  MediaPlayer armv7 <45ee55956c693d8cb16dc4c4e85075e4> /System/Library/Frameworks/MediaPlayer.framework/MediaPlayer
0x3a94a000 - 0x3a95e000  AirTraffic armv7 <b588b9fdc83d369db76f1ad5ebf2a4fa> /System/Library/PrivateFrameworks/AirTraffic.framework/AirTraffic
0x3447b000 - 0x344b6000  iTunesStore armv7 <4ff9158eb0583316b34506904b21a4f3> /System/Library/PrivateFrameworks/iTunesStore.framework/iTunesStore
0x33650000 - 0x3365b000  IAP armv7 <6703a23c7d263f33992f15c7f407b50a> /System/Library/PrivateFrameworks/IAP.framework/IAP
0x3857d000 - 0x386cc000  MusicLibrary armv7 <262f509dae9f3c128f25163a7029685b> /System/Library/PrivateFrameworks/MusicLibrary.framework/MusicLibrary
0x33ef4000 - 0x33efe000  MediaRemote armv7 <dbc251adcad43e72a31427f836a060cd> /System/Library/PrivateFrameworks/MediaRemote.framework/MediaRemote
0x342e1000 - 0x3435f000  HomeSharing armv7 <9126a007a413357b8c0275cc505cb197> /System/Library/PrivateFrameworks/HomeSharing.framework/HomeSharing
0x384fe000 - 0x3853a000  libCGFreetype.A.dylib armv7 <7a68e65e523030faa9d91478e939bc00> /System/Library/Frameworks/CoreGraphics.framework/Resources/libCGFreetype.A.dylib
0x3874f000 - 0x3876b000  libRIP.A.dylib armv7 <6e5f3b4c18e137e0a464fe13095b7dab> /System/Library/Frameworks/CoreGraphics.framework/Resources/libRIP.A.dylib
0x39519000 - 0x39937000  TextInput armv7 <ee57be9a7f723604afa6f27f85ea8b1d> /System/Library/PrivateFrameworks/TextInput.framework/TextInput
0x3647d000 - 0x3662f000  libmecabra.dylib armv7 <b59b3ee949633384bf5612da5cc73781> /usr/lib/libmecabra.dylib
0x3d4f000 - 0x3d60000  Riven armv7 <08ac9e94f78e366dad2c70bd9ccdea11> /System/Library/TextInput/Riven.bundle/Riven
0x3730f000 - 0x3731a000  Librarian armv7 <ecff1ac52f8f39bf863edadde2092aeb> /System/Library/PrivateFrameworks/Librarian.framework/Librarian
0x3a962000 - 0x3a97b000  Ubiquity armv7 <70c63bf67cff31528bbd98dc9c67c7fe> /System/Library/PrivateFrameworks/Ubiquity.framework/Ubiquity
0x34640000 - 0x34659000  ChunkingLibrary armv7 <13652bd5c5ba3e6f98435e40e91684d9> /System/Library/PrivateFrameworks/ChunkingLibrary.framework/ChunkingLibrary
0x3876b000 - 0x38789000  CoreServicesInternal armv7 <0162575a2e8b35d2915faee400c2bf30> /System/Library/PrivateFrameworks/CoreServicesInternal.framework/CoreServicesInternal
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Just a little update on this - I still can't get logs to symbolicate in Xcode (and as I've now moved my Xcode projects to a network drive I'm pretty sure I'll never get it to work), however I have found a decent enough solution in PLCrashReporter 1.2. It can locally symbolicate, which while not perfect, is normally specific enough to allow me to hone in on the problem.

[PLCrashReporter 1.2 symbolication options](https://www.plcrashreporter.org/documentation/api/v1.2-beta1/group__enums.html#ga2fccc0cc55180dce6846a39a40c57ca8)

Answer (score 1):

By just dragging the .crash file into Xcode and click "Re-symbolicate", I can get all the iOS methods symbolicated. But not my own app methods.

And I doubt if there is a possibility to get my own app methods symbolicated correctly since iOS6, because for every individual crash, the "start" method has different addresses. They used to be the same and using atos always work.

Comment: I have the same problem using Xcode organizer and the exact opposite using Atos, this is starting to get really frustrating! http://stackoverflow.com/questions/26079056/atos-does-not-symbolicate-system-frameworks-libraries-properly

Answer (score 0):

If you haven't already tried this, upgrade your mac to OSX 10.8.2. I *was* running OSX 10.7.5, and upgrading **immediately** fixed my sybolication woes.

I had tried pretty much **everything** to get my crash logs to symbolicate. I never had problems before, but a few months had passed since I'd looked at a crash log; at some point during that period I upgraded to Xcode 4.5.2. It seems to me that something with the Xcode 4.5.2 symbolicatecrash perl script does not work correctly on a mac running OSX 10.7.5. In symbolicatecrash, it calls atos to sybolicate an address; it couldn't find the matching symbols, even though I **knew for a fact** that I had the correct xcarchive. Anyhow, if you can afford the $20, spring for OSX 10.8.2 and hopefully that'll work for you.

Answer (score 0):

It is very simple if you have the archive in your Xcode and a corresponding crash log.

1. Connect your device to mac
2. goto Xcode->Window-> devices
3. Click on your device on the left panel
4. Click on view device logs
5. Select the log you want to symbolicate. (OR)  If you have a crash log file on your system then click on All logs option on the left panel  and drag the log file into left panel section.
6. Right click on the selected log and click re-symbolicate