# iOS Crash Symbolication

Tags: ios, swift, crash-reports

I'm trying to symbolicate a crash reported. I have all the necessary dsym's, the original archive, and a couple unsymbolicated crash logs. I have attempted to fully symbolicate the crash logs using the `symbolicatecrash` tool provided by Xcode, but it is only symbolicating the symbols from my app:

```
Last Exception Backtrace:
0   CoreFoundation                  0x185b1fd38 0x1859de000 + 1318200
1   libobjc.A.dylib                 0x185034528 0x18502c000 + 34088
2   AVFoundation                    0x18b3d4208 0x18b31d000 + 750088
3   Shortcuts                       0x1004d47ec 

FlashlightManager.setBrightness(brightness:) + 378860 (FlashlightManager.swift:40)
4   Shortcuts                       0x1004af9a4 specialized FlashlightJavascriptExport.toggle() + 227748 (FlashlightJavascriptExport.swift:0)
5   CoreFoundation                  0x185b276a0 0x1859de000 + 1349280
6   CoreFoundation                  0x185a06820 0x1859de000 + 165920
7   JavaScriptCore                  0x18cb80d3c 0x18c41f000 + 7740732
8   JavaScriptCore                  0x18cb8048c 0x18c41f000 + 7738508
9   JavaScriptCore                  0x18cb80924 0x18c41f000 + 7739684
```

As you can see, something in the `setBrightness` method of the `FlashlightManager` is causing an issue. However, I cannot see a way that this might be causing a crash:

```
func setBrightness(brightness: Float) throws {
    guard let avDevice = self.avDevice else {
        throw FlashlightManagerExceptions.noTorch
    }

    try avDevice.lockForConfiguration()
    if brightness > 0 {
        try avDevice.setTorchModeOn(level: brightness)
    } else {
        avDevice.torchMode = .off
    }
    currentBrightness = brightness
    avDevice.unlockForConfiguration()
}
```

Since the crash report isn't giving me any more details and I do not see anything obvious in this method, I am unable to determine the cause of the crash.

Is there any way to symbolicate the the other parts of the stack trace from `CoreFoundation`, `libobjc.A.dylib`, and `AVFoundation` so that I can get more information about this crash?

Comment: Possible duplicate of [Atos does not symbolicate system frameworks/libraries properly](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/26079056/atos-does-not-symbolicate-system-frameworks-libraries-properly)

Comment: While that answer led me down the right path, it was not actually my issue.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

It turns out that I didn't have the system framework symbols for iOS 11.0.3 locally, so `symbolicatecrash` wasn't able to symbolicate the system framework symbols.

I was able to see that I didn't have the necessary symbols by referencing the answer to this question: [Atos does not symbolicate system frameworks/libraries properly](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/26079056/atos-does-not-symbolicate-system-frameworks-libraries-properly)

Once I installed iOS 11.0.3 on my device and connected my device to Xcode, the symbols for iOS 11.0.3 were automatically downloaded and `symbolicatecrash` started working for the entire crash log.